# JPanel not showing up on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I'm trying to draw some filled rectangles on a JPanel and add that panel to a JFrame but when I run the program all I see is the JFrame. I added the JPanel using `frame.add(new RectanglePanel());` so I'm not sure why the panel is not showing up.

Frame class:

```
package h02;

import javax.swing.*;

// frame and its properties

public class RectangleFrame extends JFrame {

public RectangleFrame() {

    // JFrame object

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    // properties

    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // frame in centre
    frame.setTitle("Drawing rectangles");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new RectanglePanel());
    frame.setVisible(true);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RectangleFrame();

    }

}
```

Panel class:

```
package h02;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RectanglePanel extends JPanel {

// drawing the rectangles

public void PaintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.fillRect(110, 110, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(10, 10, 30, 120);
    g.fillRect(60, 10, 60, 100);
    g.fillRect(150, 10, 10, 20);
    g.fillRect(240, 10, 10, 20);
    g.fillRect(190, 30, 80, 30);
    g.fillRect(210, 50, 60, 20);
    g.fillRect(190, 70, 80, 50);
    g.fillRect(300, 30, 50, 90);
    g.fillRect(330, 10, 30, 20);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix it, but try adding the panel using `frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER)`. I think your panel is currently not getting sized properly, only the content pane of the frame is (and you aren't painting on the frame or frame's content pane). You could also set the preferred size using a Dimension, which overrides sizes set by the current LayoutManager. Just suggestions

Comment: Where are you setting the color for the rectangles? Add "g.setColor(Color.RED);" to you paintComponent method. You don not need to extend JFrame if you are creating one in you constructor.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I tried using frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER) but that doesn't change anything. I'm not sure how to use a dimension since I've never used it before, I'll have to look that up.

Comment: @Zyion Nowhere, fillRect just makes the rectangle completely black right?

Comment: @Zyion adding g.setColor(Color.RED); doesn't change anything either.

Comment: Actually you are right, I am testing your code and it works fine for me, maybe you just need to clean and build you project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void PaintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

should be

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Comment: Yes, this was my mistake. This is the first time I'm doing this so the fact that PaintComponent doesn't give an error (or should it? It doesn't in Eclipse) made me not question whether it was correct or not.

Comment: 1+ to the answer. @Kristoffer: this is why you should always preface your overriding methods with an `@Override` annotation, as this way the compiler *will* flag you of the error. To wiskeyspider, the method signature should be `protected` not `public`. No need to make it more visible than it has to be.

Comment: You will only get an error if you had @Override annotation on your method

Comment: @Kristoffer This is why you should use the Override annotation

Comment: Answer corrected by changing to protected and by adding the annotation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels (Edit: and others, but Hovercraft Full Of Eels was first :P) Thanks for the `@Override` tip!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a drag-and-drop editor such as the ones provided with Netbeans rather than hard code?

I find it to be much more efficient and effective.